# In Airflow Delimiter is not working perfectly with GoogleCloudStorageListOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-composer, airflow

I am using GoogleCLoudStorageList operator in Airflow Composer to list the files in the GCS bucket.
I have the parameter `'delimiter'='.gpg'` set to list only the files with .gpg extension. It works fine if there are .gpg files in the bucket. But when there is not file with .gpg extension available in the bucket, the operator is listing other files like the .txt and .csv. Is there a way out to restrict the operator to list the files we need and not other files. The `Airflow version used is 1.10.12+composer`. Sample code used is given below

```
read_files= GoogleCloudStorageListOperator(
    task_id='taskId',
    bucket=gcsbucketlocation,
    delimiter='.gpg',
    xcom_push=True
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id=google_cloud_conn_id
)
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: GoogleCloudStorageListOperator is old operator. Please try with GCSListObjectsOperator from backport providers https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/